# Display changing Python Variables on a Flask Based Website

Tags: python, web, flask, dynamic, screen-scraping

Currently building a Python3.6 Flask based Website that is hosted on a flask server and provides live prices of products taken from other sources on the web all in one place for ease of comparison.

I have a **scraper.py** file that uses BeautifulSoup4 that scrapes the web for the information. Variables containing this information are imported into a file called **app.py** that contains the flask script as a module (from scraper.py import X, Y, Z). X, Y, Z variables are passed through to the webpage via flask and displayed via the jinja 2 syntax:
`<p> {{ X }} </p>`.

The issue is that the **scraper.py** is only executed once at the time the flask server is started. However I need the variables updated at a set interval so that the lastest information is displayed.

If someone could help me by providing a soultion that I can build upon then that would be great. I have never worked with AJAX so ideally the solution would comprise of Python/Flask.

**App.py:**

```
        # Import Modules Here:
    import markdown
    import os
    import datetime

    # Import Flask Framework Here:
    from flask import Flask, flash, redirect, render_template, request, session, abort, url_for
    app = Flask(__name__)

    # Import Variables From ScrprAG.py:
    from ScprAG import AG_GRAM_SPOT, AG_OUNCE_SPOT, GLDAG_BRITANNIA, GLDAG_MAPLE, GLDAG_PHILHARMONIC, BBPAG_BRITANNIA, BBPAG_MAPLE, BBPAG_PHILHARMOIC

    # ./Home Script + Portfolio Page:
    @app.route("/")
    @app.route("/index")
    def index():
        return render_template('index.html', AG_GRAM_SPOT_WEB=AG_GRAM_SPOT, AG_OUNCE_SPOT_WEB=AG_OUNCE_SPOT, GLDAG_BRITANNIA_WEB=GLDAG_BRITANNIA, BBPAG_BRITANNIA_WEB=BBPAG_BRITANNIA, GLDAG_PHILHARMONIC_WEB=GLDAG_PHILHARMONIC, BBPAG_PHILHARMOIC_WEB=BBPAG_PHILHARMOIC, GLDAG_MAPLE_WEB=GLDAG_MAPLE, BBPAG_MAPLE_WEB=BBPAG

_MAPLE)
```

**Scraper.py:**

```
    # Import Modules Here:
import requests
import urllib.request
import time
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

# Variable List:
url_spot_gram = (None)  # AG_GRAM_SPOT
AG_GRAM_SPOT = (None)

url_spot_ounce = (None)  # AG_OUNCE_SPOT
AG_OUNCE_SPOT = (None)

url_1 = (None)  # GLDAG_BRITANNIA
GLDAG_BRITANNIA = (None)

url_2 = (None)  # BBPAG_BRITANNIA
BBPAG_BRITANNIA = (None)

url_3 = (None)
GLDAG_PHILHARMONIC = (None)

url_4 = (None)
BBPAG_PHILHARMOIC = (None)

url_5 = (None)
GLDAG_MAPLE = (None)

url_6 = (None)
BBPAG_MAPLE = (None)

# Scraping Script Here:

def job():

    # Current Silver Spot Price: GRAM:
    global AG_GRAM_SPOT
    url_spot_gram = 'https://www.bullionbypost.co.uk/silver-price/silver-price-per-gram/'
    response = requests.get(url_spot_gram)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')
    AG_GRAM_SPOT = soup.find('span', {'name': 'current_price_field'})

    # Current Silver Spot Price: OUNCE:
    global AG_OUNCE_SPOT
    url_spot_ounce = 'https://www.bullionbypost.co.uk/silver-price/week/ounces/GBP/'
    response = requests.get(url_spot_ounce)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')
    AG_OUNCE_SPOT = soup.find('span', {'name': 'current_price_field'})

    # Script: GOLD.CO.UK | Silver Britannia
    global GLDAG_BRITANNIA
    url_1 = 'https://www.gold.co.uk/silver-coins/silver-britannia-coins/1oz-silver-britannia-dog-2018/'
    response = requests.get(url_1)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')
    GLDAG_BRITANNIA = soup.find('td', {'id': 'total-price-inc-vat-1'})

    # Script: BULLIONBYPOST.CO.UK | Silver Britannia
    global BBPAG_BRITANNIA
    url_2 = 'https://www.bullionbypost.co.uk/silver-coins/britannia-silver-ounce/1oz-silver-britannia-best-value/'
    response = requests.get(url_2)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')
    BBPAG_BRITANNIA = soup.find('td', {'id': 'price-inc-vat-per-unit-1'})

    # Script: GOLD.CO.UK | Silver Philharmonic
    global GLDAG_PHILHARMONIC
    url_3 = 'https://www.gold.co.uk/silver-coins/austrian-silver-philharmonic-coins/silver-philharmonic-2020/'
    response = requests.get(url_3)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')
    GLDAG_PHILHARMONIC = soup.find('td', {'id': 'price-inc-vat-per-unit-1'})

    # Script: BULLIONBYPOST.CO.UK | Silver Philharmoic
    global BBPAG_PHILHARMOIC
    url_4 = 'https://www.bullionbypost.co.uk/silver-coins/austrian-philharmonic/2020-1oz-austrian-philharmonic-silver-coin/'
    response = requests.get(url_4)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')
    BBPAG_PHILHARMOIC = soup.find('td', {'id': 'price-inc-vat-per-unit-1'})

    # Script: GOLD.CO.UK | Silver Maple
    global GLDAG_MAPLE
    url_5 = 'https://www.gold.co.uk/silver-coins/candian-silver-maple-coins/1oz-canadian-maple-silver-coin-2020/'
    response = requests.get(url_5)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')
    GLDAG_MAPLE = soup.find('td', {'id': 'price-inc-vat-per-unit-1'})

    # Script: BULLIONBYPOST.CO.UK | Silver Maple
    global BBPAG_MAPLE
    url_6 = 'https://www.bullionbypost.co.uk/silver-coins/britannia-silver-ounce/1oz-silver-britannia-best-value/'
    response = requests.get(url_6)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')
    BBPAG_MAPLE = soup.find('td', {'id': 'price-inc-vat-per-unit-1'})
    time.sleep(60)

    print(BBPAG_MAPLE)
    print(BBPAG_PHILHARMOIC)
    print(BBPAG_BRITANNIA)
    print(GLDAG_MAPLE)
    print(GLDAG_PHILHARMONIC)
    print(GLDAG_BRITANNIA)

while True:
    job()
```

Comment: Save the values inside a static folder, make a routine in flask that updates the values and  then use ajax to refresh the values

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your pages are rendered at the end of the functions... I don't know any way to update the values inside the {{}} in the Jinja template... They have already been rendered.

My suggestion is to use Ajax and to create a REST Api for the values.

- Every possible product requests its price every x seconds inside the browser via ajax;
- Every x seconds the Flask application refreshes the price of all possible itens;
- Flask serves the desired values via an API.

Comment: Any chance you could give me an example of what it should look like?

Answer (score 0):

You can periodically fetch the backend from the frontend via http requests (unidirectional communication)

But if you want to update immediately you can use websockets (bidirectional communication) you can send a message to the frontend without the periodic requests.

But websockets require libraries on the frontend and the backend (if you don't want to build it from scratch). Flask has some nice WebsocketLibraries like [Flask SocketIO](https://flask-socketio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/).

If you don't need the immediate response, I recommend using periodically sent http requests until you run into some limitations.

Comment: So if i wanted it to update every 5 minutes then flask-stocketIO would be a viable solution?

Comment: no. if you only want to update every 5 minutes and the interval always stays the same, then use http requests.